# Spark Streaming fails and can't recover

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

My Spark Streaming application fails every once in a while and can't recover from these failures.

When the failures occures, I see this exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Query [id = 061e72ac-9918-425c-bb2f-0941eb3f3018, runId = 772d3d62-c2d1-4b5a-b26a-3b28c4099e2b] terminated with exception: 
Execution of the stream null failed. Please, fill a bug report in, and provide the full stack trace.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:330) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:208) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Execution of the stream null failed. Please, fill a bug report in, and provide the full stack trace.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.toInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:542) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:324) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:208) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSource.getBatch(FileStreamSource.scala:235) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$3(MicroBatchExecution.scala:548) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:293) ~[scala-library-2.12.15.jar:?]
```

When this error occures, Spark Streaming can't recover by itself, but only when I delete a checkpoint file as described below, the application is back to run normally.
When I look at the checkpoint folders, I see that:

- commits/100
- sources/0/100
- offsets/101

As seen, there's an extra offset checkpoint file.
When I delete this file, the job is back to normal.

I'm using: emr-6.9.0, Spark 3.3.0, Hadoop 3.3.3.

I don't know if that has something to do with that error, but I occasionally see these errors as well (also for jobs that run successfully):

```
Cannot create temp dir with proper permission: /mnt3/s3
```

Any idea why that error might happen?
Can I make Spark to recover from that issue by itself, without the need to delete that file manually?